# Button drawable causes Resources$NotFoundException on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I'm using a button in one of my activities. That button has a drawable on the left side, however it seems to be causing error on some devices (detected by CrashLytics)

Here is the code of my button

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/deleteCat"
    android:onClick="deleteCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/baseline_delete_forever_black_24"
    android:text="Delete Category"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    />
```

And here is the errors I have

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bialy.zonelauncher/com.app.name.AddCategory}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #87: Binary XML file line #87: Error inflating class Button
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
       ...
```

and the specific error is here

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f08006c
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:267)
       ...
```

I've looked up the resource ID and found it to be the button drawable, which is not located in drawable-24 folder or anything similar.

Devices that have this error are running android 8.0, 8.1, 9.0

What is the problem here?